# VM: Azure adding secondary StaticIP to existing VM

Tags: azure, virtual-machine

Is it possible to associate a secondary Static IP address to an existing Azure VM on the same nic? How could this be done?

(Windows Server 2016 VM)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer on how to add a second IP to the same NIC card on an existing VM on Azure but you must install components through the powershell and then manually configure the NIC inside the windows VM environment.

Full Article here, credit to Pierre Roman

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/canitpro/2017/03/15/step-by-step-setup-multiple-public-ips-on-a-vm-in-azure/

Comment: I thought you were talking about the internal one